kex_exchange_identification or banner exchange causing time out issue while ssh into amazon ec2
I am trying to ssh into a amazon linux 2023. My colleague can log in fine using the same private key. It seems like it initially connects then times out. This is the command and output:
% ssh -i my-key.pem ec2-user@x.x.x.x -v
OpenSSH_9.7p1, OpenSSL 3.3.1 4 Jun 2024
debug1: Reading configuration data /opt/homebrew/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file my-key.pem type -1
debug1: identity file my-key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.7
kex_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out
banner exchange: Connection to x.x.x.x port 22: Operation timed out

I did install openssl and openssh via homebrew to attempt to fix the issue, however, issue still continued. I also restarted machine with no luck. As mentioned before, my colleague could log in, so networking should be fine (VPN to VPC). What steps should I take to diagnose this? Another thing to note, it may be to do with some setting on my Macbook which was set by my company.
